# How to use helper method of my engine generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I needs use helper method, but an error is returned.

This is my helper module

```
# app/helpers/my_engine/application_helper.rb
module MyEngine
  module ApplicationHelper

    def app_name
      Rails.application.class.parent_name.underscore
    end

    def engine_name
      Module.nesting.last.name.underscore
    end

  end

end
```

This is my generator

```
# lib/generators/my_engine/my_gen_generator.rb
module MyEngine
  class InstallGenerator < ::Rails::Generators::Base
    include MyEngine::ApplicationHelper

    desc "Desc"

    p engine_name

  end
end
```

The error returned is: `Error: undefined local variable or method engine_name...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **extend** instead of **include**
[Here's a link](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/)